Same website - 2 DNS, 1 Slow and 1 if Fast
When I connect via an old DNS to my website (also API calls to this DNS) it is super fast, loading data is fast, on the new DNS it is slow ! really slow like 10 times. it used to be fast.
I use django PostgreSQL on apace2.
IT IS POINTING TO THE SAME IP!
I know the ip should be stored already in lookup table, so I dont get how the site is still slow after few clicks...
Slow:
https://dash.instasck.com/
Fast:
https://www.instasck-dash.duckdns.org/
We did not change anything, so I am not sure.
Check video:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6oexc2y58se0eppak6rj1/slowDNS.mp4?rlkey=uv5e0gq3eqcby3ob1dr3fjmo4&st=l3z016s5&dl=0
Ping is the same

does not make sense:



What kind of requests and what timings are you seeing in Chrome's "Devtools"?

A traceroute might be educational here too.

When inspecting a request in Dev Tools, go to the “Timings” tab. That’s where the relevant data is. // That being said, I cannot access your DuckDNS domain but the other one isn’t terribly slow, ~230ms.

@DanielB the 5 seconds is not the DuckDns but the http://dash.instasck.com/
BTW now it is fast again .. so I am realy confused

I can't help but notice that one url is HTTPS and the other is HTTP. DNS does have some impact on SNI, Host Header, and HTTPS certificate validation.

your "slow" link in the question is http://

Any one with a proper solution ? get logs from apache 2 ?

So the issue is first that my developers are not well trained to install & config servers.
But for the real answer, we need to understand the difference between MPM and WSGI, I tried to increase MPM threads and process, which results in nothing, since MPM is the proxy for REQ camming from outside, but not handling the run running of the python server, the WSGI on the other hand needed to set with Process=CPU NUMBER and Threads to simulations running will work.
That was the case in the other DNS it was just triggered another process for that (another false configurations).

Since the ping statistics points to almost the same average:
--- dash.instasck.com ping statistics ---
107 packets transmitted, 107 received, 0% packet loss, time 106086ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 270.601/276.377/348.555/12.000 ms
and
--- www.instasck-dash.duckdns.org ping statistics ---
93 packets transmitted, 93 received, 0% packet loss, time 96794ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 271.031/276.862/337.189/11.296 ms
So... no matter the DNS until here because the IP is already resolved.
The next thing you could look would be the Certificate, but as I can see, both are using the same standards.
You could take a look also if you have turned off browser's cache on one of the windows while recording the video, exceptionally.
Could you be running your python application in a dev deployment? It could be more unstable than the production's ready deployment.
What's your webserver configuration? Minimal configurations could lead to this kind of behaviour too.

thank you. it seems that each DNS creates a saparate process so that is the reason one is still fast, while we exploring the issue on the other.
